# Impersonation works with asmx but not with svc

Tags: wcf, web-services, impersonation

My simple HelloWorld.asmx works fine and passes my credentials through to the database server, but my HelloWorld.svc tries to login with the web server credentials. I have

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

in the web.config and this binding for the WCF service:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Both asmx and svc are on the same IIS7 .Net 4 web server. 
What else does WCF need to impersonate?

Answer (score 2):

OK, got it. Need this attribute on the OperationContract:

```
    [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
```